# Find Date Difference in BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have an issue with datetime.

I have two strings.
e.g `24-9-15` and `2-10-15`.
Both are two strings.

I want to find out the difference (in days) between them.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Parse the 2 strings to roDateTime objects.

Reference - http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roDateTime

2) get the time in seconds for both dates by doing `date1.AsSeconds()` and `date2.AsSeconds()`

3) Subtract the 2 times, so you have the time difference in seconds.

4) Divide this seconds by 3600 to convert into hours, then divide by 24 to convert into days

ie. `(seconds/3600) / 24`

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try this out.

Comment: @akshat can you provide a full code example in the answer. That would be helpful, rather than a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
date1 = CreateObject("roDateTime")
date2 = CreateObject("roDateTime")
diffInSeconds = date1.asSeconds() - date2.asSeconds()
print "seconds lapsed " diffInSeconds
```

Comment: your way is good. But, How to parse date and time string value in a date?

Answer (score 0):

If those are your strings, I do not think there are any functions that will help you. You may have to do it manually. Still, you can look at the [ifDateTime](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifDateTime#ifDateTime-FromSeconds(numSecondsasInteger)asVoid) functions and see if they help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetDurationString(totalSeconds = 0 As Integer) As String
remaining = totalSeconds
hours = Int(remaining / 3600).ToStr()
remaining = remaining Mod 3600
minutes = Int(remaining / 60).ToStr()
remaining = remaining Mod 60
seconds = remaining.ToStr()

If hours <> "0" Then
    Return PadLeft(hours, "0", 2) + "hours " + PadLeft(minutes, "0", 2) + "minutes " + PadLeft(seconds, "0", 2) +" seconds"
Else
    Return PadLeft(minutes, "0", 2) + "minutes " + PadLeft(seconds, "0", 2)+" seconds"
End If
End Function
```

======================================================================

```
Function PadLeft(value As String, padChar As String, totalLength As Integer) As String
While value.Len() < totalLength
    value = padChar + value
End While
Return value
End Function
```